# Where is the entity ID stored?

Tags: 7, entities

I have an installation which I am trying to upgrade from Drupal 6 without much success. I have decided to manually port the database over.

I realized that in a fresh installation of Drupal 7, node has entity ID = 1 whereas in another installation, node has entity ID = 2.

Where is the table storing this data located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for `hook_entity_info` and `entity_extract_ids`. The former specified a base table and the id key, the latter allows to extract the ID from the entity.